# Usage of 断然 as の-adjective?

Tags: particle-の, adjectives

> 今年の欧州マイル路線では古馬や牡馬を交えても**断然の**ＮＯ・１
> At this year's European Mile route, even with other types of horses participating, (アルファセントーリ) is the absolute number one

I know that 断然 is a taru adjective so shouldn't it be 断然たるＮＯ・１ instead?
Is 断然 a noun or an adjective here? if it's an adjectives, can I use other taru adjective with の instead of たる, like if they were の-adjectives? (I guess to not sound very strict/archaic)

Other sentences I found:

> 1. 現時点で**断然の**１番人気になりそうなのはアイルランドの３歳牝馬アルファセントーリです。
> 2. 全点に撥水加工を施したemuは、他ブランドに比べても**断然の**撥水性を保っています！
> 3. 私はずいぶん昔にBBTの単科科目を履修したことがあるのですが、その時に比べても**断然の**パワーアップ！！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I use it only as a standalone adverb meaning "by a huge margin" or "definitely (better)" when comparing things. That is to say, I usually use it with 方が/より, and I almost never attach の/な/に to 断然.

Regarding its no-/na-adjectival usage, I can find a few examples on BCCWJ, so it may not be entirely incorrect. But the number is very small as compared to its adverbial usage (i.e., no の/な/に at all), and I personally wouldn't recommend it.

> - ダイビングやシュノーケルなら、バリより**断然に**沖縄の離島が最高にきれいですよ。
> - 愛用してると以前に比べると疲れ具合が**断然に**違ってきます。
> - 私の馬券は**断然の**1番人気のカワカミプリンセスからでしたが、…

As a taru-adjective, 断然たる(態度, 意志, etc) usually means "resolute", "determined" or "firm". 断然(と) means "determinedly", etc. (e.g., 政府に対して断然(と/たる/φ)抵抗を続ける) This meaning is fine in serious novels, but is too stiff, literary or outdated for a daily usage. 断然たる撥水性 sounds too grandiose and even a little funny to me.

Answer (score 0):

Your question made me curious so I looked it up on a few different Japanese online dictionaries.
断然 has two different forms, the adjective (形容動詞) form and the adverb (副詞) form.
The meanings depend on the form.

The adjective form, the と or たる form, refers to one's attitude of being uncompromising in the face of strong opposition.

The adverb form refers to being on a completely different level compared to others.
You can use の(断然**の**1番) or な(断然**な**1番) with it, or just have no particle at all, i.e.「ほかの店より**断然**美味しい」.

So in your example, 断然の1番 refers to being "number 1 by far" and is being used in its adverbial form.

Comment: Downvoter, any suggestions for improving answer would be helpful.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but の and な usages would not be adverbial.